# Is the obligatory omission of tense/aspect/mood marking in polar interrogatives common?

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology, interrogatives

In a language I'm studying for a field methods class, the range of tense/aspect/mood marking on verbs seems to be relatively limited in interrogative clauses. For example, in some verbs, a past tense marker must be omitted if the verb is found in a negative interrogative. If it is found in an A-not-A question (the language is not Sinitic but is Sino-Tibetan), then the A part also drops the tense marking.

This got me thinking about some questions:

- Is this common crosslinguistically? Are there any other examples?
- If this is common, are there any proposed explanations? e.g. are questions conceptually more complex and therefore TAM markers are removed to simplify things?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the past tense marker in question have any connection to perfectivity? A negative interrogative seems like the kind of context where the perfect/imperfect distinction isn't particularly relevant and the imperfect might be preferred

Comment: I'm not sure tbh - the language is poorly documented (there was going to be a grammar on it, but the linguist has passed away) and we don't really have enough data from our elicitation, so we've actually been calling it 'preterite' for the time being. It's certainly possible that it's connected to the perfective (especially as there's a progressive form that seems to apply to both the past and the present), so your explanation sounds plausible!

Comment: Why the secrecy about the language you are studying?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to give more details for others to be able to understand and answer my question, so I think it's good to play safe about it, since the consultant didn't explicitly give us permission to post the data online.